# Prevent Babel from using .babelrc

Tags: babeljs

When requiring('babel/register)() even if I tell it a custom .babelrc path it still loads the original .babelrc too.
How can I prohibit it to read .babelrc?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is this is impossible and therefore you should specify your custom BABEL_ENV each time you're using Babel and in your .babelrc you make an "env" section with configuration for each of your BABEL_ENV